# How to obtain a general solution of a linear homogeneous first-order PDE?

Tags: linear-algebra, partial-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

Writing the equation as $$u_x+a(x,y)u_y+u(x,y)=0$$
I am wondering how to solve this generally.
Is there any general method or solution exist?

Comment: don't you need initial condition for $u$ on some curve in the $xy$ plane? define the family of characteristic curves by $dy/dx = a(x,y)$ starting at a pint on the curve where initial condition is given. on this char curve pde reduces to an ode $du/dx = -u$ which has solution $u=u_0e^{-x}.$ now fill the plane with char curves, and trace each curve to initial values.